# How to search nth child alone in jstree

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to search only 3th child in `jstree`. I tried `$('#userlogs li>a ').find('span:third-child').jstree('search', searchstring)` - this is not working. In my code inside li anchor tab is there. In that anchor tab 4 spans r there. I want to search only 3rd `span`. Please help me to resolve this issue

**Code:**

```
    $(' #userLogs ').jstree({
    'search': {
    case_insensitive: true,
    show_only_matches : true,
    show_only_matches_children: true,
    fuzzy: false,

            },
            'plugins': ['search']
        }).on('search.jstree', function (nodes, str, res) {
                if (str.nodes.length === 0 && searchString.length !=0 ) {
                        $('#userLogs').jstree(true).hide_all();
                        $('#userLogs').append('<p id="searchFound">'+" No search Found "+'</p>');
                 }
        });

    $("#searchTerm").keyup(function ()  {
    searchString = $(this).val();
    $('#userLogs').jstree(true).show_all();
    //$('#userLogs li > a').find('span:nth-child(3)').jstree('search', searchString);
    $('#userLogs li > a').find('span:third-child(3)').jstree('search', searchString);

    }
```

I can't send my html code here. inside li tab 4 spans are there. While searching anchor tab is automatically getting added. I want to search only 3rd span content.

Comment: Please provide the code that generates the tree, so we can run it and see the context of what you tried.

Comment: Anyone pls help me to resolve this issue.. I need urgent solution for this issue..

Comment: This code alone does not generate the tree nodes. Please provide the code that generates the tree, so we can run it and see the context of what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems here:

```
$('#userLogs').jstree(true).show_all();
//$('#userLogs li > a').find('span:nth-child(3)').jstree('search', searchString);
$('#userLogs li > a').find('span:third-child(3)').jstree('search', searchString);
```

Your commented line was closer, because there is no such selector as `:third-child`, but you also want `span:nth-of-type(3)` rather than `:nth-child(3)`, as nth-child looks for *any* child.

But the bigger problem is that the jstree method works on a jstree **object**, not on some random element. Assuming (and it's a big assumption!) that that third span you're looking for contains the node ID, this should work:

```
var jstree = $('#userLogs').jstree(true)
jstree.show_all()
var nodeId = $('#userLogs li > a').find('span:nth-of-type(3)')
jstree.jstree('search', searchString, inside=nodeId.html())
```